# Interesting php for loop

Tags: php

```
 for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++) 
 {
     echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
 }
```

Well this is for loop but i want next output:

```
This number is 1 is Red
This number is 2 is blue
This number is 3 is green
This number is 4 is orange
This number is 5 is Red
This number is 6 is blue
This number is 7 is green
This number is 8 is orange
This number is 9 is Red
This number is 10 is blue
This number is 11 is green
This number is 12 is orange
```

-
Basically red, blue, green, orange repeating every four times - it is brain teaser.

Comment: Sorry, this website is not for brain teasers. And to spoil it: modulus.

Answer (score 2):

This is a teaser for you too

```
echo "<pre>";
$li = new LimitIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator(array("red","blue","green","orange"))), 0, 500);
foreach ( $li as $key => $teaser ) {
    printf("The number is %d %s %s", $key + 1, $teaser, PHP_EOL);
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.org/GJulU5yI)

Comment: @hakre .. i trust you can reduce this to just 2 lines ...

Comment: That not, but just seeing that the numbering is broken, it could work this way. It's actually a nice example of the `InfiniteIterator`. http://codepad.org/p3Pdc6xp

Comment: @hakre `for($colors->rewind(), $i = 1; $color = $colors->current(), $i <= 500; $i ++, $colors->next()) {` ..... could not stop smiling ... not again with your `for loop` .... this is nice .. I did not expect anything less ... nice

Comment: Looking at it again .... that was cool its really an interesting way to use `for` with `Iterators`

Answer (score 0):

Use a modulo function to decide upon the color to use based on the counter value:

```
$colors=array ('red','blue','green','orange');
for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++)
{
    $color=$colors[$i%4];
    echo "This number is ".$i." is ".$color."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: how come someone give +1 if it has an error!

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im its more common than you think ..

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - it's more helpful if you point out what the error actually is

Comment: `$color` != `$colors` ...... Yes you also added `$color=$colors[$i%4];` by overwritten your original array

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - Even with a typo (obviously 1 missing 's'), the content of an answer can be helpful. Nobody is perfect, and nobody expects bug free example code, even more since all here are volunteers.

Comment: @andrewsi oops. Sorry I forgot to mention. The out put of this program does not contain color names. The cause of this error is missing `s`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @martinstoeckli. Many users around the world will reference this SO question and also many a user will copy paste code directly from here. Your code **MUST** be error free. Its not a big software where bugs are not uncommon. Its a small snippet. How come you have bug here? If its normal for you, do you think every 5 lines of your code file contains an error is normal?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - Actually i'm a big fan of clean-code development, so i like error free code. My point is, that you cannot expect everybody to test his examples, before posting. The system of SO is built in a way, that fast writers are in advantage. And copying from SO/internet should not prevent people from thinking themselves, these are developers after all.

Comment: Had to correct the code ... can't continue to see it that way .....

Comment: @martinstoeckli in SO answerers should supply error free code. If code is  not tested and answerer is uncertain about it he should state it in words. But should not post erroneous code.

Comment: I switched the code back to the original version which was perfectly fine, except of that small typo in the first line: colors instead of color. I do appologize for that typo. I switched the code back since using singualr and plural versions of the same word makes the meaning of the variables clear. The code is tested and words as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$colours = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Orange"];

for ($i=0; $i<500; $i++)
{
    $colour = $i%4;
    echo "The number is " . $i . " is ".$colours[$colour]. "<br />";
}
```